# How do I splice a dataframe into smaller dataframes based off of the year in a datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to make smaller tables based off of a dataframe, based on the decade.

I've divided taken the **Year** out of the **Air Date** column, but I can't seem to append each row to a new table based off of which decade it is.

Here is what I have so far.

```
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Air Date']).year

the_1980s, the_1990s, the_2000s, the_2010s = [], [], [], []
for date in df:
    if date['Year'] > 1980 and date['Year'] < 1990:
        the_1980s.append(date)
    elif date['Year'] > 1990 and date['Year'] < 2000:
        the_1990s.append(date)
    elif date['Year'] > 2000 and date['Year'] < 2010:
        the_2000s.append(date)
    else:
        the_2010s.append(date)
```

I keep getting this error
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: You would need to either add your original dataframe or some analog to make this a reproducable problem. Here's some further information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Looking at your code and error though, I would image that type of `date` is a string. But I can't say for certain until I see the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to this is:

```
the_1980s = df[(1980 < df['Year']) & (df['Year'] < 1990)]]
```